# Solutions to the equation $x^2=1$ in a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

In a cyclic group, say $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ where $p$ is a prime, why does the equation $x^2=1 \mod p$ only have two solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean when r=2 there is only two solutions? If so, it is because $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Yes I mean for x^2=1

Comment: Have you learned that a cyclic group of order $n$ has *exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for each $d$ dividing $n$*?

Comment: @Rramiro de la Vega: : How that, the set of units is  not a group?

Comment: @Bernard: Right, I misinterpreted the notation.

Comment: Ah! You thought of non-zero elements?

Answer (score 2):

Because a quadratic equation in a field (more generally in an integral domain) has at most two roots. This is because $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x) \iff p(x) $ is divisble by $\;x-\alpha\;$ and $\;\deg p(x)q(x)=\deg p(x)+\deg q(x)$.

Comment: To add to this, observe that $x=\pm 1$ are solutions and since there can be at most two, these are the only two.

Comment: Yes. I think it was implicit in the O.P.'s question. Do you think I should add this fact?

Comment: It can't hurt! Maybe O.P. Is a diligent comment reader and it won't be necessary.